# Question about Pasch's axiom and why doesn't it intersect vertices

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a convex quadrilateral, point E on BC, F and G different points on CD such that (GFC), and H is a point on AD. Prove that the lengths EG and FH intersect.

[image]

My attempt was to look at triangle GCE and line HF and to use Pasch axiom on them. To use that axiom first i need to check that line HF doesn't pass through G, C and E. I know it doesn't pass through G i C because of order (GFC) but why doesn't it pass through E?

If i somehow would know that it doesn't pass through E, I could use axiom because i know that line HF intersects GC because of (GFC) and that would mean that HF needs to intersect GE or CE. And it would not intersect CE because that would be contradiction with Pasch axiom but applied to ABCD(it would pass through it three sides).  So it needs to intersect GE in some point S.

So I need help with why HF doesn't pass through E?

After that I would look at triangle HFD and line EG in the same way and got that GE intersects HF in some point S'. Finally, I should show that S=S'?

Comment: You wrote: "HF would not intersect CE because that would be contradiction with Pasch's axiom applied to ABCD". If HF can't intersect BC because of Pasch's axiom, then it cannot pass through E.